# Is it possible to assign subdomain to module? For example seller.domain.com to seller module

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Below is my virtual host on local system :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin kishan@localhost.com
DocumentRoot /opt/lampp/htdocs/advanced
ServerName dev.com
ServerAlias dev.com
ErrorLog logs/mysite.local-error_log
CustomLog logs/mysite.local-access_log common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin kishan@localhost.com
DocumentRoot /opt/lampp/htdocs/advanced
ServerName seller.dev.com
ServerAlias seller.dev.com
ErrorLog logs/mysite.local-error_log
CustomLog logs/mysite.local-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Backend for administation so set for the dev.com/webxadmin/login

below is procedure to change name to backend/web/index.php to "webxadmin".

```
<?php
namespace common\components;


class Request extends \yii\web\Request {
    public $web;
    public $adminUrl;

    public function getBaseUrl(){
        return str_replace($this->web, "", parent::getBaseUrl()) . $this->adminUrl;
    }


    /*
        If you don't have this function, the admin site will 404 if you leave off 
        the trailing slash.

        E.g.:

        Wouldn't work:
        site.com/admin

        Would work:
        site.com/admin/

        Using this function, both will work.
    */
    public function resolvePathInfo(){
        if($this->getUrl() === $this->adminUrl){
            return "";
        }else{
            return parent::resolvePathInfo();
        }
    }
}
```

backend/config/main.php

```
'components' => [
        'request' => [
            'class' => 'common\components\Request',
            'web'=> '/backend/web',
            'adminUrl' => '/webxadmin'
        ],
```

Here is .htaccess on root

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

# deal with admin first

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(webxadmin)
RewriteRule ^webxadmin/assets/(.*)$ backend/web/assets/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^webxadmin/css/(.*)$ backend/web/css/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/backend/web/(assets|css)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(webxadmin)
RewriteRule ^.*$ backend/web/index.php [L]




RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(assets|css)
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ frontend/web/assets/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ frontend/web/css/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(frontend|backend)/web/(assets|css)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ frontend/web/index.php
```

Here is my module inside backend/module/seller/seller.php
Working with yii-2 project i have e-commerce site i am trying to access my seller module on sub-domain like seller.dev.com with all controller and action?

but i need access my module in sub-domain how can i do that?

I tried this method inside the component->urlmanager did not work.

```
'seller.dev.com/'=>'seller/index/login',
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you got this subdomain configured on the server?

Comment: i tried with this but still not working..

Comment: Do you expect that this one line of code will magically create you a subdomain? It doesn't work that way.

Comment: i am not expecting this only one method i have tried with .htaccess file also but might be problem is i have created request component for administrator url so i am also confused on what do i set on .htaccess tried with backend path,url path still it not work..i need guide who have done before. i read one issue question related to what i want in url i dont understand how it is work?

Comment: Look at this issue it is close working but how? : https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/2646

Comment: This is different issue. You need to configure your server's subdomain first. You can point virtual server to this module's path right from the start so there is no need for rule. Rules like this are made mainly for different behavior in case of different server names. See [this section](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html#rules-with-server-names) in Guide.

Comment: look at my updated question with full description :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you are working with custom request component and .htaccess.
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

```
# deal with admin first

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(webxadmin)
RewriteRule ^webxadmin/assets/(.*)$ backend/web/assets/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^webxadmin/css/(.*)$ backend/web/css/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/backend/web/(assets|css)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(webxadmin)
RewriteRule ^.*$ backend/web/index.php [L]




RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(assets|css)
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ frontend/web/assets/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ frontend/web/css/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(frontend|backend)/web/(assets|css)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ frontend/web/index.php
```

End of the .htaccess file add this below line.

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ backend/web/index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for matching a [rule based on hostnames](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html#rules-with-server-names) is:

```
'http://seller.dev.com'=>'seller/index/login',
```

If that does not work, you should look for the problem inside your custom rewrite logic or the Request class. I do not really understand what you are trying to do there.

Since Yii 2.0.11 you can also use the following syntax to have a protocol relative URL which works with `http` and `https`:

```
'//seller.dev.com'=>'seller/index/login',
```